# Restricting direct access to angular chatbot app

Tags: angular, azure, kubernetes, nginx, traefik

I've got an Angular main app running on an Nginx pod in the Azure Kubernetes Cluster, and inside the app there is an iframe. When we click on the iframe, it opens a separate chatbot Angular app that is running on another nginx pod.
How can I restrict the access of the chatbot Angular app such that users are only able to access the chatbot app through the main app and not through the chatbot's URL?

From a DevOps perspective, I've tried:
1] K8s service communication:-  From parent angular pod we can connect to angular app using url like:- chatbot-svc-name.chatbot-namespace-name.svc.cluster.local:8082

I have written ingressroute(traefik) as well to route the traffic :-
Host(`chatbot-svc-name.chatbot-namespace-name.svc.cluster.local`) && PathPrefix(`/chatbot-client`)

But I'm not able to access the chatbot app in the parent app.

2] tried below networkpolicy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-external-access
  namespace: chatbot-ns
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chatbot-client
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
         matchLabels:
            project: main-app
      podSelector:
         matchLabels:
            app: main-client
```

But just like k8s service communication it didn't work in main app when I tried to open in browser using iframe.

Restrict the access of the chatbot Angular app such that users are only able to access the chatbot app through the main app and not through the chatbot's URL

Comment: When you say you have tried  service communication, do you mean you created a  service?
So three things you need to do here to achieve your ask
1.  Create a Kubernetes service for the chatbot Angular app.
2.  Create a Kubernetes network policy for the chatbot Angular app.
3.  Update the main app to use the Kubernetes service to access the chatbot Angular app. Have you tried these steps?

Answer (score 0):

In order to restrict access to the chatbot Angular app so that users can only access it through the main app and not through the chatbot's URL, you can create a Kubernetes service to expose the chatbot Angular app to the main app.

```
kubectl create service nodeport --name chatbot-svc chatbot-ns --tcp=8082:8082
```

This will create a service named `chatbot-svc` in the `chatbot-ns` namespace. The service will expose port `8082` on the chatbot Angular app to port `8082` on the service node.
With a combination of the above service and the network policy you have created, the Kubernetes service will expose the chatbot Angular app to the main app, and the network policy will restrict access to the chatbot Angular app to the main app.
You can also create a network policy using.

```
kubectl create networkpolicy --name restrict-access-chatbot chatbot-ns --selector app=chatbot-client --ingress podSelector=app=main-client
```

So three things you will do here-

1. Create a Kubernetes service for the chatbot Angular app.
2. Create a Kubernetes network policy for the chatbot Angular app.
3. Update the main app to use the Kubernetes service to access the chatbot Angular app.

Once you have configured the Kubernetes service and network policy, you can access the chatbot Angular app from the main app using the following URL:

```
http://chatbot-svc:8082/chatbot-client
```